# Cascade WMTS XML file with MapServer

Tags: gdal, mapserver, wmts

I need to cascade a WMTS service via MapServer.
I used gdal_translate to obtain an XML file. The XML file loads correctly in QGIS.

Meanwhile, when I test MapServer I get the following error :

> msDrawRasterLayerLow(): Unable to access file. Corrupt, empty or missing file '[...].xml' for layer 'global_png'. Cannot parse CRS 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:2154'

gdalinfo and gdal_translate don't return error. I needed to define GDAL_DATA environnement variable. I tryed to define PROJ_LIB too but this didn't solve or modify the error message.

Here is the mapfile layer:

```
LAYER

    NAME "global_png"
    STATUS ON
    
    TYPE RASTER
    UNITS METERS
    DEBUG 5
    
    DATA "file.xml"
    EXTENT 200635.1160934336 6775687.697226753 344228.7212134335 6895858.930506754
    
    
    METADATA    
        "wms_srs"       "EPSG:2154"
        "wms_title"    "title (png)"
        "wms_format"    "image/png"
        "wms_name"      "global_png"
        
    END # METADATA
    
END
```

Comment: Please write a minimal but complete mapfile that others can use easily for testing. If the WMTS service that you use is not open then use some open WMTS instead, for example https://demo.mapserver.org/mapcache/wmts/?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: Where do you set the projection in the map file?  In the GetCapabilities response does mapserver report any errors?

Comment: It looks that the WMTS service i try to cascade encounters a malfunction. My question should be standby.